# Why won't the string push or pop in stack

Tags: c++, string, data-structures

This is an assignment given to me.
I am a noob just started programming.
The string as a whole won't push onto the stack and how to pop it.

Problem statement:- divide a whole string consisting of a full name, divide the string into 3 parts to get the first name middle name and surname and display them in the order of surname first name middle name USING STACKS ONLY.

I've tried using 2D stack

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
using std :: string;

char s1[100];
char s2[50],s3[50],s4[50];
int i=0,j=0,k=0,max1=9,top=-1;
char stack[10][10];
char re[10];



void push(char val[])
{
    if(top>=max1)
    {
        cout<<"Stack overflow";
    }
    else
    {
     top++;
     int a=0;
     for (int i=0;i<stack[top]['\0'];i++)
     {
       stack[top][a]=val[i];
       a++;
     }
   }
}


char* pop()
{
  if(top<0)
  {
      cout<<"Stack underflow";
  }
  else
  {
    //for(int j=0;j<=top)
    for(int i=0;i<stack[top]['\0'];i++)
    {
         re[i]=stack[top][i];
        top--;
        return re;
    }

  }
}
void divstring()
{
    for(i=0;s1[i]!=' ';i++)
    {
s2[i]=s1[i];
    }
    s2[i]='\0';
    i++;
    while(s1[i]!=' ')
    {
s3[j]=s1[i];
j++;
i++;
    }
    s3[j]='\0';
    i++;
    while(s1[i]!='\0')
    {
s4[k]=s1[i];
k++;
i++;
    }
    s4[k]='\0';
    i++;
}

int main()
{
//clrscr();
    cout<<"Enter the string: ";
   gets(s1);

    divstring();
    cout<<"The 1 part is "<<s2<<endl;
    cout<<"The 2 part is "<<s3<<endl;
    cout<<"The 3 part is "<<s4<<endl;
  //  getch();
  push(s1);
  push(s2);
  push(s3);

  cout<<pop();
  return 1;
}
```

There are no compile time errors but the strings don't get pushed onto the stack nor popped.

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Comment: What do you think this bit is doing? `stack[top]['\0']`

Comment: Whichever C++ book told you to use `gets()` -- you need to get another C++ book. Whichever instructor told you to use that, you need to get a different instructor.

Comment: Why don't you use `std::stack`?

Comment: Give us an example of the program input.

Comment: `push(s1); push(s2); push(s3);` should this be `push(s2); push(s3); push(s4);`? I'm guessing `s1` will be too big to fit in your "stack"

Comment: What do you expect this statement `i<stack[top]['\0']` to do?

Comment: I too don't understand what `i<stack[top]['\0']` was supposed to do and how that relates to the passed `val[]`

Comment: Any reason a [`std::stack`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack) won't work instead?

Comment: Are you in a class that is teaching Anti-C++ by any chance?

Answer (score 2):

There's multiple problems here.

There is no such thing as a 2D stack. A stack is one dimensional. It's got one usable end. In C++, you use std::stack, push(), pop() and empty().

You need to get rid of the global variables.

You seem to want to implement your own stack. You need to decide, do you want to implement a stack, that is one question. Or, do you want to use an existing stack to perform the assignment? that's a different question. I can't tell between the two.

You should use std::string.

You don't handle boundary condition. For example passing a string without spaces will loop infinitely in

```
for(i=0;s1[i]!=' ';i++)
```

Answer (score 1):

The push function is very confused, here's a working version

```
void push(char val[])
{
    if (top >= max1)
    {
        cout << "Stack overflow";
    }
    else
    {
        top++;
        int i = 0;
        for (; val[i] != '\0'; i++)
            stack[top][i] = val[i];
        stack[top][i] = '\0';
    }
}
```

There are many ways you could improve this, you could use the C `strcpy` function instead of copying your strings by hand. Or, heaven forbid, you could use some C++, like `std::string` and `std::stack`.

Comment: thanks i impleented it

Comment: are there any updates required in pop function??

Comment: Yes, that doesn't work either, again the loop is wrong. I don't know what you think `i<stack[top]['\0']` is doing, but it's not right. I'll leave you to think about that one.

Comment: thanks for the help i figured it out